# VBA If statement not working properly and skipping cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a VBA code such that it checks each cell in a range for specific values ("V", "FH", "WM", "N", "LM", "S", "Y", "CP", "IN", "OUT", "END", "G", "H") and if the cell does not contain it, it makes it empty.

The code is the following:

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False

End Function
```

And then I use it like this:

```
For Each sCell In checkSRange
        If IsInArray(sCell.Value, Array("V", "FH", "WM", "N", "LM", "S", "Y", "CP", "IN", "OUT", "END", "G", "H")) Then
        abcd = 2
        Else: sCell.Value = ""
        End If
    Next sCell
```

The problem is that this code works for a lot of values but for some reason, cells with the value of "Z" and "M" do not get deleted. I tried adding this to the code:

```
If sCell.Value = "Z" Or sCell.Value = "M" Then
        sCell.Value = ""
        End If
```

But even this did not work...

What is the issue????? Thanks.

Comment: First check: Does the cell really contain `"M"` or `"Z"` or maybe `"M "` or `"Z "` (with an additional blank)? Use `IsInArray(trim(sCell.Value), Array("...` and see if that helps.

Comment: That should still not make it found in the given array when OP tried it without the work-around @FunThomas Also just tested it, "Z" and "M" get deleted just fine for me.

Comment: Your 'IsInArray' function can be replaced by a single instr statement  e.g. 'If Instr("V,FH,WM,N,LM,S,Y,CP,IN,OUT,END,G,H", sCel.value)=>0 then'.  Or more flexible, by adding the individual strings as keys to a scripting.dictionary.

Comment: Could it just be a visual thing, i.e. you deleted something in column B but in Colum A there are values that "spill over" in B? `Something     Z` with the Z showing in column B? Or the Z value not being part of your `checkSRange`?

Comment: @freeflow That would include too many e.g. F, H, W, M... etc.

Comment: `arr(i) = stringToBeFound` or `sCell.Value = "Z"` are case-sensitive comparisons (unless `Option Compare Text`) i.e. if it's a lowercase `z`, it won't be considered equal. To ignore case, you can use the following: `If StrComp(arr(i), stringToBeFound, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`.

Comment: Or just `If arr(i) = UCase(stringToBeFound)` which seems simpler, no? @VBasic2008

Comment: @Notus_Panda No, if you want the function to be flexible because next time you won't have only uppercase strings in the array and it won't work expectedly. Optionally, you could also upper the array element: `If UCase(arr(i)) = UCase(stringToBeFound) Then`.

Comment: I just have a quick question. `"Z" and "M"` are not in the argument array. Why does OP expect it is deleted?

Comment: @taller Since he couldn't get it to work, he must have moved it into the separate (bottom-most) piece of code.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Got it. I hope your guess is right.

Comment: @VBasic2008 OP stated *"and if the cell does not contain it, it makes it empty"*, he only wants to keep these values and empty the rest so not finding Z/M is a desired result but they had issues with getting rid of those (apparently).

Comment: @Notus_Panda In the context of this post, `contain` is quite a loose word and could mean both, the value is equal to or the value contains. I think it's the former because otherwise, the function would be wrong. In the latter case, one would probably use `Instr` after sorting the array by length descending to prevent the shorter strings from excluding the longer ones.

Comment: I checked and there is no white spaces. Also, I should be clear. The column has value is equal Z/M and not "contain" it. @Notus_Panda

As for the case sensitivity, I do want that the z and m get deleted even if they are lower case but in my table, I checked and everything was upper case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, so sorry but I found the answer. Turns out that I was using the checkSRange. It was not selecting the complete range for the last 20 cells were not getting checked. My code works but also the code of @Vasily also works! I switched to his code over mine.

But I just wanted to ask, is it possible to make it faster? (Already have disabled screen update) Since it is checking each cell, I think it is a bit too slow...

Comment: As this is not an answer: please update your question or ask a new on.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in OP comments, you need to remove case sensitivity (using `Option Compare Text` or `UCase` ...) and white spaces from cell value using `Trim` function. Also, additional variant using `Dictionary` and it `Exists` method below:

```
Sub checkRangeValues()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim dKey
    For Each dKey In Split("V FH WM N LM S Y CP IN OUT END G H")
        dic.Add dKey, Nothing
    Next dKey
     
    For Each cl In [A1:A15] 'checkSRange
        If Not dic.exists(Trim(cl)) Then
            cl.Value = ""
            cl.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

test:

[image]

Comment: I used your code but the Z is still there...

Answer (score 1):

### Replace Range Mismatches: `Application.Match` vs `Dictionary`

- On the few tests I performed, the `Match` version emerged a bit faster on a large dataset e.g. using a single area range with 10M cells, the result was 30-45 (`Match`) vs 35-60 seconds (`Dictionary`).

**`Application.Match`**

Usage

```vb
Dim CheckStrings As Variant:
CheckStrings = Array( _
    "V", "FH", "WM", "N", "LM", "S", "Y", "CP", "IN", "OUT", _
    "END", "G", "H")
' ...???
Dim checkSRange As Range
' ...???
ReplaceMismatches checkSRange, CheckStrings, Empty
```

The Method

```vb
Sub ReplaceMismatches( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        CheckStrings() As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal Replacement As Variant = Empty)

    Dim arg As Range, crg As Range, Data() As Variant, Indices() As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long, cCount As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    
    For Each arg In rg.Areas
        
        rCount = arg.Rows.Count
        cCount = arg.Columns.Count
    
        If rCount = 1 Then
            If cCount = 1 Then ' single cell
                If IsError(Application.Match(arg, CheckStrings, 0)) Then
                    arg.Value = Replacement
                End If
            Else ' single row
                Data = arg.Value
                Indices = Application.Match(arg, CheckStrings, 0)
                For c = 1 To cCount
                    If IsError(Indices(c)) Then Data(1, c) = Replacement
                Next c
                arg.Value = Data
            End If
        Else ' multiple rows
            Data = arg.Value
            c = 0
            For Each crg In arg.Columns
                c = c + 1
                Indices = Application.Match(crg, CheckStrings, 0)
                For r = 1 To rCount
                    If IsError(Indices(r, 1)) Then Data(r, c) = Replacement
                Next r
            Next crg
            arg.Value = Data
        End If

    Next arg

End Sub
```

**Dictionary**

Usage

```vb
Dim CheckStrings As Variant:
CheckStrings = Array( _
    "V", "FH", "WM", "N", "LM", "S", "Y", "CP", "IN", "OUT", _
    "END", "G", "H")
' ...???
Dim checkSRange As Range
' ...???
ReplaceMismatchesDict checkSRange, CheckStrings, Empty
```

The Method

```vb
Sub ReplaceMismatchesDict( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal CheckStrings As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal Replacement As Variant = Empty, _
        Optional ByVal MatchCase As Boolean = False)

    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = MatchCase + 1 ' True = -1; False, Binary = 0; Text = 1;

    Dim Value As Variant
    
    If IsArray(CheckStrings) Or IsObject(CheckStrings) Then
        For Each Value In CheckStrings
            If Not IsError(Value) Then dict(Value) = Empty
        Next Value
    Else
        If Not IsError(Value) Then dict(Value) = Empty
    End If
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim arg As Range, Data() As Variant, IsMatch As Boolean
    Dim rCount As Long, cCount As Long, r As Long, c As Long

    For Each arg In rg.Areas

        rCount = arg.Rows.Count
        cCount = arg.Columns.Count
    
        If rCount * cCount = 1 Then ' single cell
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = arg.Value
        Else ' multiple cells
            Data = arg.Value
        End If
                
        For r = 1 To rCount
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Value = Data(r, c)
                If Not IsError(Value) Then
                    If dict.Exists(Value) Then IsMatch = True
                End If
                If IsMatch Then IsMatch = False Else Data(r, c) = Replacement
            Next c
        Next r

        arg.Value = Data

    Next arg

End Sub
```

**A Test**

```vb
Sub Test()
    
    Dim CheckStrings() As Variant: CheckStrings = Array( _
        "V", "FH", "WM", "N", "LM", "S", "Y", "CP", "IN", "OUT", _
        "END", "G", "H")

    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Sheet1.Range("A2:J1000001")
    
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    
    ' Dictionary
    ReplaceMismatches rg, CheckStrings, Empty
    Debug.Print Timer - t: t = Timer
    
    ' Application.Match
    ReplaceMismatchesMatch rg, CheckStrings, Empty
    Debug.Print Timer - t

End Sub
```

### Clear Column Mismatches Using `Application.Match` (Initial Post)

```
Dim CheckStrings As Variant:
CheckStrings = Array( _
    "V", "FH", "WM", "N", "LM", "S", "Y", "CP", "IN", "OUT", _
    "END", "G", "H")

Dim checkSRange As Range

' ...???

' Assuming 'checkSRange' has more than one cell!

With checkSRange
    Dim Data() As Variant, Indices() As Variant, r As Long
    Data = .Value
    Indices = Application.Match(.Cells, CheckStrings, 0)
    For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
        If IsError(Indices(r, 1)) Then Data(r, 1) = Empty ' or '= ""'
    Next r
    .Value = Data
End With
```

**Is String in List?**

- Here is just a rewrite of the function which allows you to choose whether the comparison is case-sensitive. By default, it's not.
- In the calling procedure clean the string if necessary e.g. with `Application.Trim` and whatnot.
- Since a `For Each...Next` loop is used, `CheckStrings` (`As Variant`) can be an array of any dimensions, a collection, a dictionary, or an array list.

```vb
Function IsStringInList( _
    ByVal CompareString As String, _
    ByVal CheckStrings As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal MatchCase As Boolean = False) _
As Boolean
    Dim CompareMethod As Long: CompareMethod = MatchCase + 1
    Dim CheckString As Variant
    For Each CheckString In CheckStrings
        If StrComp(CheckString, CompareString, CompareMethod) = 0 Then
            IsStringInList = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next CheckString
End Function
```